# oAuth sample for ADFS Windows 2012 R2

Tags: oauth-2.0, adfs

I have installed ADFS that came with Windows 2012 R2. I have registered the client using Windows Powershell and obtained the client_id. I need a sample that works on oAuth 2.0 with ADFS.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm new with ADFS and I don't know if my solution is the best, even I'm not sure if it is correct, but it worked for me. Anyway, just in case, I'll share it.

Based on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13727466/oauth2-and-dotnetopenauth-implementing-google-custom-client), here is my custom client for ADFS using OAuth2. My code is for MVC4 application using [DotNetOpenAuth](http://dotnetopenauth.net/).

```cs
public class AuthServiceOAuth2Client : OAuth2Client
{

    #region Constants and Fields

    /// <summary>
    /// The authorization endpoint.
    /// </summary>
    private const string AuthorizationEndpoint = "https://your_adfs/adfs/oauth2/authorize";

    /// <summary>
    /// The token endpoint.
    /// </summary>
    private const string TokenEndpoint = "https://your_adfs/adfs/oauth2/token";

    /// <summary>
    /// The _app id.
    /// </summary>
    private readonly string _clientId;

    /// <summary>
    /// The _app secret.
    /// </summary>
    private readonly string _clientSecret;

    #endregion


    public AuthServiceOAuth2Client(string clientId, string clientSecret)
        : base("ADFS")
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(clientId)) throw new ArgumentNullException("clientId");
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(clientSecret)) throw new ArgumentNullException("clientSecret");

        this._clientId = clientId;
        this._clientSecret = clientSecret;
    }

    protected override Uri GetServiceLoginUrl(Uri returnUrl)
    {
        StringBuilder serviceUrl = new StringBuilder();

        serviceUrl.AppendFormat("{0}?grant_type=authorization_code", AuthorizationEndpoint);

        serviceUrl.AppendFormat("&redirect_uri={0}", returnUrl.ToString());
        serviceUrl.Append("&response_type=code");
        serviceUrl.AppendFormat("&client_id={0}", _clientId);
        serviceUrl.AppendFormat("&resource={0}", "your_resource");

        return new Uri(serviceUrl.ToString());
    }

    protected override IDictionary<string, string> GetUserData(string accessToken)
    {
        // do stuff
        return new Dictionary<String, String>();
    }

    protected override string QueryAccessToken(Uri returnUrl, string authorizationCode)
    {
        StringBuilder postData = new StringBuilder();
        postData.AppendFormat("client_id={0}", this._clientId);
        postData.AppendFormat("&redirect_uri={0}", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(returnUrl.ToString()));
        postData.AppendFormat("&client_secret={0}", this._clientSecret);
        postData.AppendFormat("&grant_type={0}", "authorization_code");
        postData.AppendFormat("&code={0}", authorizationCode);

        string response = "";
        string accessToken = "";

        var webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(TokenEndpoint);

        webRequest.Method = "POST";
        webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

        try
        {

            using (Stream s = webRequest.GetRequestStream())
            {
                using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(s))
                    sw.Write(postData.ToString());
            }

            using (WebResponse webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse())
            {
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    response = reader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }

            var json = JObject.Parse(response);
            accessToken = (string)json["access_token"];
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return null;
        }

        return accessToken;
    }

    public override AuthenticationResult VerifyAuthentication(HttpContextBase context, Uri returnPageUrl)
    {
        string code = context.Request.QueryString["code"];
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(code))
        {
            return AuthenticationResult.Failed;
        }

        string accessToken = this.QueryAccessToken(returnPageUrl, code);
        if (accessToken == null)
        {
            return AuthenticationResult.Failed;
        }

        IDictionary<string, string> userData = this.GetUserData(accessToken);
        if (userData == null)
        {
            return AuthenticationResult.Failed;
        }

        string id = userData["id"];
        string name;

        // Some oAuth providers do not return value for the 'username' attribute. 
        // In that case, try the 'name' attribute. If it's still unavailable, fall back to 'id'
        if (!userData.TryGetValue("username", out name) && !userData.TryGetValue("name", out name))
        {
            name = id;
        }

        // add the access token to the user data dictionary just in case page developers want to use it
        userData["accesstoken"] = accessToken;

        return new AuthenticationResult(
            isSuccessful: true, provider: this.ProviderName, providerUserId: id, userName: name, extraData: userData);
    }
}
```

Pay attention on the `redirectUri` because it should be the same you registered on ADFS.

I have also coded a little Web API project based on the Vittorio's [post](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2013/07/30/securing-a-web-api-with-windows-server-2012-r2-adfs-and-katana/) to retrieve the user info.

Hope it helps.