# Does any one work with ADFS Windows 2012 R2 using oAuth

Tags: oauth-2.0, adfs2.1

Does any one work with ADFS Windows 2012 R2 using oAuth. I tried to find the stuff but all in vain. I am struggling for many days but no one helped me. Please please help me on this

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm working with ADFS using OAuth. I'm stucked now ... but I could make it work. Just a simple auth flow. Look at my answer of your question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23639778/2414652) to create a custom client using DotNetOpenAuth.