# ADFS 2012 R2 oAuth 2.0 SSO sample .NET

Tags: oauth-2.0

Can any one point me in the right direction. I want oAuth2.0 .NET sample that works with ADFS 2012 R2. The sample should manage the session cookies so my client application don't need to enter the password again and again for true SSO experiecne.

Comment: I have the exact same request as you do, but there doesn't seem to be any samples out there, and not even any good documentation for how to utilize the OAuth support in ADFS 2012 R2.

Comment: I found one http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2013/07/30/securing-a-web-api-with-windows-server-2012-r2-adfs-and-katana/

Comment: Recently, I have made a custom client using ADFS OAuth and DotNetOpenAuth... just that, I have still a ton of things to do but maybe my custom client helps you to continue your work. My custom client is posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23639778/2414652)

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps you.

-Securing a Web API with Windows Server 2012 R2 ADFS and Katana
http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2013/07/30/securing-a-web-api-with-windows-server-2012-r2-adfs-and-katana/

-Access Control Service 2.0
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh147631.aspx